# Jquery .html .animate

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am trying to build a step carousel with only two steps.
I want to load the picture into the right div, slide it to the left, then load the same picture into the left div and make that visible with css again to get back to the original state and be ready to repeat the process with a different image.

It kinda works. After loading the page, on the first click everything works smoothly. On the second click the inserted picture is only loaded AFTER the animation is complete. Even if the animation time is set to 20000 for example.

So it is not a image loading issue but some issue with the code. .html cannot have a callback function - so how can I do this correctly?

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    $('#unt').click(function () {
        $('#panorama2').html('<img src="img/panoramabild-1.jpg">');
        $('#panoramaslider').animate({
            'margin-left': '-1240px'
        }, 600, function () {
            $('#panorama').html('<img src="img/panoramabild-1.jpg">');
            $('#panoramaslider').css({
                'margin-left': '0'
            });
        });
    });
    $('#phi').click(function () {
        $('#panorama2').html('<img src="img/panoramabild-2.jpg">');
        $('#panoramaslider').animate({
            'margin-left': '-1240px'
        }, 600, function () {
            $('#panorama').html('<img src="img/panoramabild-2.jpg">');
            $('#panoramaslider').css({
                'margin-left': '0'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am still working on this. It seems that the second .html is reversing the first .html, so weird ...

Comment: Nevermind. I nested the "panorama2" inside "panorama" in the HTML part  ... should work fine now.